# Deactivate advanced data security

Tags: azure

I am running a small Azure instance as a playground that I rarely use. But I'm paying for:

[image]

Which I really don't want, because that is more than 50% of what I'm paying in total and my data is complete garbage.

How do I deactivate that? I found multiple places where it should be, but it got moved around over the years and I can't find it anywhere:

- I can't change my security center pricing, at some point it apparently was part of that?
- Databases used to have an "advanced data security" tab. Not any more.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found it:

Go to your database -> Security -> Security Center -> Turn off the entire Azure Defender here. It might be activated in general or on database level, maybe both.

And remember kids, don't accept "free" services from a stranger. They will make you pay for it, even if their strategy should be to just be happy when people want to get into their tech stack.

EDIT: I really wasn't billed for the advanced data security. But only once:
[image]

Now the database says that I have the Defender configured, but I really don't.
[image]

When I click on it, I'm told to activate the defender:
[image]

I am speechless. It's just a couple of bucks, but just how much money are companies paying for stuff they don't really want..

Comment: "Go to your database -> Security -> Security Center -> Turn off the entire Azure Defender here. It might be activated in general or on database level, maybe both." 
Where? I dont see any button where I can turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

This was the path I took as of July 2023. I imagine this will be renamed / moved at some point in the future.

1. Go to one of your Azure SQL Servers
2. Click the "Microsoft Defender for SQL" tile (mine said partially configured)
3. There's a message that says

> Enablement Status: Enabled at the subscription level (Configure)

4. Click configure
5. Now there's tile that says Microsoft Defender for SQL **ON** *Microsoft Defender for SQL costs 20.595 AUD/Server/month*
6. Change to OFF and save.

This is not a recommendation to turn it off. You should assess for yourself whether this is suitable.

Comment: Thank you.  I have been looking for this solution for too long!

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it too. Not sure though...

[image]

[image]